# At what point can we assume the tip of a fin is adiabatic?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, heat

Let's say there is a fin that is 1mm thick, extends 8mm from the surface, and is 10 mm wide. The fin is exposed to a moving fluid. Can we assume the adiabatic tip condition and use the characteristic, "Corrected", length for calculations?

Comment: Using the corrected length does not assume an adiabatic tip. The corrected length is intended to make a non-adiabatic tip fit into equations used for an adiabatic tip. *Not* using the corrected length – i.e., taking $L_c=L\ $ – means assuming an adiabatic tip.

Answer (score 1):

The error due to assuming the tip is adiabatic is approximately given by the area ratio of the tip to the total surface area of the fin. That is, $error = 8 mm^2 / 160 mm^2 $.